In which case(s) are the uploaded animated gifs being resized?
I read:

The limitations are mostly imposed by third-party systems we use during the image upload process, and also when resizing animated gifs. [Troy Gould]

In which case(s) are uploaded animated gifs being resized?

Good question, as they don't really resize the gif, but rather only its first frame to create the image thumbnails. (e.g. this.)
